# Printing real dimensions of an image

Tags: delphi, printing

Hi mates i want to print a picture i generated i use the following code

```
  Printer.BeginDoc;
  Printer.Canvas.Draw(0,0,img1.Picture.Bitmap);
  Printer.EndDoc;
```

It works but the image it prints is very small how can i print the actual size of the image as it appears on the screen ?

Thanks very much.

Comment: If you 'generated' the 'picture' using Windows GDI, then the only reasonable solution is to 'generate' it directly on the printer's canvas, instead. If you want to separate the two processes, then generate a EMF and 'play' this onto the printer's canvas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call [`Canvas.StretchDraw()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Graphics.TCustomCanvas.StretchDraw) instead. However, be prepared for the results to be less than impressive. Trying to scale a raster image in this way will lead to very blocky results. Vector images are what you need in order to be able to scale to printer resolutions.

```
var
  Scale: Integer;
...
Scale := Min(
  Printer.PageWidth div Bitmap.Width,
  Printer.PageHeight div Bitmap.Height
);
Printer.Canvas.StretchDraw(
  Rect(0, 0, Bitmap.Width*Scale, Bitmap.Height*Scale), 
  Bitmap
);
```

The scaling I chose here will preserve the aspect ratio and make the image as large as possible when printed.

Comment: It's not as it appears on the screen but is a starting point. Thanks +1

Comment: With a raster image you are not going to get it to appear as it does on the screen. Printers have 5-10 times higher resolution that screen.

Comment: The downvoter has probably already forgotten about this question or your answer. Seeing as about every answer you give at the moment, you probably stood on someone's toes and now have acquired your own personal downvoting nemesis, just like @Andreas had (at least at one stage). Just let it go. Even if you get a response, I feel you won't get anything useful out of such a conversation.

Comment: @David: I know. I also know how/when you stood on his toes, but didn't think it mattered too much.

Answer (score 3):

You should achieve better results if you resize the image to an intermediate bitmap (with a size suitable for the printer resolution) using one of the resamplers in [JCL](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help%3aStretch@Cardinal@Cardinal@TResamplingFilter@Single@TGraphic@TBitmap) or [Graphics32](http://graphics32.org/) and then you print the resized bitmap.

The following routine will try to get the same size in printer as in the screen:

```
uses
  JclGraphics;

procedure PrintGraphic(source: TGraphic);
var
  dest: TBitmap;
  destWidth, destHeight,
  printerPixelsPerInch_X,  printerPixelsPerInch_Y,
  printerLeftMargin, printerTopMargin: integer;
begin
  printerPixelsPerInch_X := GetDeviceCaps(Printer.Handle, LOGPIXELSX);
  printerPixelsPerInch_Y := GetDeviceCaps(Printer.Handle, LOGPIXELSY);
  printerLeftMargin      := GetDeviceCaps(Printer.Handle, PHYSICALOFFSETX);
  printerTopMargin       := GetDeviceCaps(Printer.Handle, PHYSICALOFFSETY);

  dest := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    destWidth  := source.Width  * printerPixelsPerInch_X div Screen.PixelsPerInch;
    destHeight := source.Height * printerPixelsPerInch_Y div Screen.PixelsPerInch;

    Stretch(destWidth, destHeight, rfLanczos3, 0, source, dest);

    Printer.BeginDoc;
    try
      Printer.Canvas.Draw(printerLeftMargin, printerTopMargin, dest);
      Printer.EndDoc;
    except
      Printer.Abort;
      raise;
    end;
  finally
    dest.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TFormMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not PrinterSetupDialog.Execute then
    exit;

  PrintGraphic(Image1.Picture.Graphic);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC (I don't have Delphi in front of me to check right now), `TPrinter` has a `PixelsPerInch` or similar property that has to be set so printing is at the correct resolution. The default value does not match the screen, which is why the image gets printed so small. Most newbies to using `TPrinter`don't know to set the property.

Comment: No `PixelsPerInch` in `TPrinter`. Are you perhaps thinking of `TFont.PixelsPerInch`.

Comment: Nah; he's thinking of `GetDeviceCaps(Printer.Handle, LOGPIXELSX)` (or `LOGPIXELSY`). See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144877(v=VS.85).aspx). I'd use `SCALEFACTORX` (or `Y`) instead as the flags param, though.

Comment: @David and @Ken: neither of those is what I was thinking of. I'll have to wait until Monday when I get Delphi in front of me. I recall seeing earlier discussions that use actual properties of `TPrinter` to address sizing issues, but I do not remember offhand the particular details yet.