# Is there a reliable way to draw a bitmap on a Tprinter canvas?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I have created a print preview object which allows me to organise several graphic objects from different sources onto a printed page.

In order to render these objects on the printer canvas I have to first render them to a bitmap of the calculated size and then render the bitmap to the Tprinter canvas at the correct positions using the canvas.draw(x,y,bitmap) method.

I found out early on that a device independent bitmap is required and set the pixel format to pf24bit.

Tried this on the office HP laserjet, works fine, HP colour Deskjet works fine, Cannon colour printer however does not work or occasionally gives intermittent graphics at random points.

Now if I get the graphical objects to render directly to the printer canvas, then all work OK.

Rendering directly to the printer canvas however is not a workable long term solution for me for various reasons.

So, my question is, what is it about the Tprinter.canvas that makes it hardware dependent and is there any workarounds ?

Some example code which divides the page up into 4 quadrants with margins and cell padding and puts a graphical object in each quadrant. Each graphical object has a RenderToBitmap method which draws the graphics.

```
procedure TMultiPrintForm.PrintBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var w,h,h2,w2,mv,iw,ih,pv,cw,ch:integer; Abmp:Tbitmap;
begin
  Abmp:=Tbitmap.create;
  Abmp.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
  try
    with Printer do
    begin
      w:=pagewidth;   
      h:=pageheight; 
      h2:=h div 2; 
      w2:=w div 2;
      mv:=h*margin.value div 200;    //margin percentage div 2 
      pv:=h*padding.value div 400;   //padding percentage div 4
      iw:=w-mv;                      //internal width
      ih:=h-mv;                      //internal height
      cw:=(iw-mv) div 2-pv;          //Quadrant Cell Width
      ch:=(ih-mv) div 2-pv;          //Quadrant Cell Height
      Abmp.width:=cw;
      Abmp.height:=ch;
      If Fsources[0]<>nil then
      begin
        Fsources[0].rendertoBitmap(Abmp);
        canvas.draw(mv,mv,Abmp);
      end;
      If Fsources[1]<>nil then
      begin
        Fsources[1].rendertoBitmap(Abmp);
        canvas.draw(w2+pv,mv,Abmp);
      end;
      If Fsources[2]<>nil then
      begin
        Fsources[2].rendertoBitmap(Abmp);
        canvas.draw(mv,h2+pv,Abmp);
      end;
      If Fsources[3]<>nil then
      begin
        Fsources[3].rendertoBitmap(Abmp);
        canvas.draw(w2+pv,h2+pv,Abmp);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    printer.Enddoc;
    Abmp.free;
  end
end;
```

On further investigation around the net, I accumulated some suggestions into a PrintBitmap procedure which uses a technique recommended by Microsoft.

I replaced all the Canvas.draw calls with PrintBitmap calls (it assumes begindoc and enddoc are set outside the calls).

Being as its the weekend, I can't test it on the problem printers in the office but it does at least not break the printing on the home HP Deskjet printer (which works anyway with both methods).

```
procedure PrintBitmap(X,Y:integer; Abmp:Tbitmap);
var Info: PBitmapInfo;
  InfoSize,ImageSize: DWORD;  Image: Pointer;
  DIBWidth, DIBHeight: LongInt;
begin
  with Printer do
  begin
    GetDIBSizes(Abmp.Handle, InfoSize, ImageSize);
    Info  := AllocMem(InfoSize);
    Image := AllocMem(ImageSize);
    try
      GetDIB(Abmp.Handle, 0, Info^, Image^);
      with Info^.bmiHeader do
      begin
        DIBWidth := biWidth;
        DIBHeight := biHeight;
      end;
      StretchDIBits(Canvas.Handle, X, Y, DIBWidth, DIBHeight, 0, 0,
      DIBWidth, DIBHeight, Image, Info^, DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
    finally
      FreeMem(Image, ImageSize);
      FreeMem(Info, InfoSize);
    end
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You should post a minimal code example of your problem.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "random positions"? Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777870/printing-real-dimensions-of-an-image) may be of help.

Comment: To answer your direct question (last paragraph): Printers support much higher (and many different) resolutions. On the screen, they're Pixels per Inch (eg., 96 or 120); on printers, they're Dots Per Inch (DPI). Common values are 150x150, 300X300, 600x600,900x900, and 1200x1200. This obviously means that an image which would be 1" x 1" (96x96) would appear much differently when drawn on a printer (96 pixels wide on a 1200 DPI printer is less than 1/12th of an inch). For how to fix it, show your code now so we have a place to start.

Comment: Code sample added as requested.

Comment: What does `RenderToBitmap` do?

Comment: @Leonardo. Its the graphical objects drawing method which draws itself on a bitmap instead of on the screen. The graphical objects in this case are charts, but there are several other graphical object types in the program that also need to be printable.

Comment: the reason I ask is that you create a bitmap, then resize it to proper dimensions, and then your objects draw onto it - but do your method of drawing themselves take care about dimensions in the target canvas? That's the kind of thing that may be important...

Comment: @Leonardo. Yes the objects all work in real world floating point dimensions and convert to graphical coordinates during painting. Usually, the visible screen is just a small viewport into a much bigger canvas which can be panned and zoomed. Thus the drawing surface integer dimensions are all handled automatically by the renderer. Each object has an alternative 3D OpenGL renderer as well since they have both 2D planar and 3D representations.